Locally on $D_+(fg)$ the sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{Proj(S)}(nd)$ are generated by $(f/g)^n=f^{2n}/(fg)^n$
Today I read this proof at Stacks 01MU. The following is the very first sentence of the proof but I do not really understand.

Let $S$ be a graded ring and $X=Proj(S)$. Fix $d\geq 1$ and $f,g$ homogeneous elements such that $deg(f)=deg(g)+d$. Then locally on $D_+(fg)$ the sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X(nd)$ are generated by $(f/g)^n=f^{2n}/(fg)^n$

Professor de Jong claims it is just by definition of twisted sheaf. For example take $d=1$, is it true that $\mathcal{O}_X(n)|_{D_+(fg)}$ is generated by $(f/g)^n$?

Two very minor improvements: the full last name of the author of the work in question (at least as displayed on his webpage and wikipedia) is "de Jong", not just "Jong"; next, it's nice for other readers to include the name of the work and not just a blind link.

Yes. Recall (by Stacks 01M7, for instance) that $\Gamma(D(fg),\mathcal{O}_X(nd))=S(nd)_{(fg)}$, the homogeneous localization at $fg$ of the regular module shifted by $nd$, which is naturally a module over the ring $S_{(fg)}$.
An element of $S(nd)_{(fg)}$ is therefore a fraction $p/(fg)^a$ where $\deg p - a(2\deg g + d)=nd$, and we want to show that we can pick $q/(fg)^b\in S_{(fg)}$ (i.e. with $\deg q = b(2\deg g + d)$) so that $$\frac{q}{(fg)^b}\cdot\frac{f^n}{g^n} = \frac{p}{(fg)^a}.$$ But $\frac{pg^{2n}}{(fg)^{n+a}}$ works: $$\frac{pg^{2n}}{(fg)^{n+a}}\cdot\frac{f^n}{g^n} = \frac{p}{(fg)^a}.$$

Let me also remark that this section of the Stacks Project is trying to cover all of the bases for all of the ways things can go weird with Proj - it may be better for a first or second read to focus on Hartshorne's, Vakil's, or similar treatments to get a decent conceptual understanding in the nice cases and then branch out to this very general treatment later as needed.

Thank you very much for the help and that was really helpful.
